# NHibernate Search and Eager Fetching

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-search

I used Lucene and NHibernate Search session to search

```
IFullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.session);
var fullTextResult = fullTextSession.CreateFullTextQuery<T>("my query");
```

In my entity mapping I did not specify option of lazy load or eager fetching because I prefer to control more flexible like Linq provider `var customers = session.Query<Customer>().Fetch(c => c.Orders)`. However `IFullTextSession` does not provide such capability.

I would like to see if anybody has a good idea to use NHibernate search and I can specify eager fetching.